# Find the expected area of scpherical caps

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables, spheres

On a sphere of radius $R$ we randomly choose $N$ circles of radius $r$ , $r < R$ (this means that centers of circles uniformly distributed on 
on a sphere of smaller radius).
Each of the circles uniquely determines the spherical cap. What is the expected area of the union of these spherical caps?

Because of caps intersection I think simple approach with repeated integral doesn't seem to be the way this problem should be solved.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "what is the expected area of the union of these spherical caps"?

Comment: @Wouter yes, exactly. I am going to edit the question

Comment: you mean the spherical cap as one of the two portions of the sphere with lesser area that is demarcated by the circle?

Comment: @AritroPathak yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of the following line of reasoning, but it gives a reasonable-looking result...

Let the area of the sphere be $S$ (a function of $R$), and the area of a single spherical cap $C$ (a function of $R$ and $r$).

Then the probability that a randomly-chosen point on the sphere is *not* on the cap is
$$1-\frac{C}{S}$$

For $N$ caps, the probability that a randomly-chosen point on the sphere does not lie on any of them is
$$\left(1-\frac{C}{S}\right)^N$$

We could interpret this probability as the fraction of $S$ not expected to be covered by caps.

So you would expect the surface area to be
$$S\left(1-\left(1-\frac{C}{S}\right)^N\right)$$

This is reasonable for $N=1$ (gives $C$) and $N\rightarrow \infty$ (gives S)